# How to use Imacros to remove a part of element inspector?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have an element inspector script like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGiaP.jpg)
I want to use Imacros to remove "**display: none;**", Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display="";undefined;}
```

Comment: The code works great on .iim file but when i put on .js file, it not work and I got error (SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)). ==> The code on imacros javacript: code+="URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display="";undefined;} \n";
iimPlayCode(code);

Comment: Just escape the quotes: `code+="URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById(\"g-recaptcha-response\").style.display=\"\";undefined;} \n"; iimPlayCode(code);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried and not work on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: Everybody please help me! I want to run this code in javacript :      URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display="";undefined;}          and run javacript with imacros addon! Please help!!!

Comment: What's the problem? If you don't like the previous way, try this: `window.location.href = 'javascript:{document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style.display=""; undefined;}';` .