# iMacros inspect element and delete page code

Tags: imacros

Good morning everyone wanted to help create a more imacro code can not
I have found that I have to use javascript via imacro with this command

```
  URL GOTO = javascript:
```

I wanted to know which command javacript I use to take the name
'Display: none;'

the complete code would be this

```
   <Textarea id = "g-recaptcha-response" name = "g-recaptcha-response" class = "g-recaptcha-response" style = "width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid # c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none; "> </ textarea>
```

more I wanted to remove only the display: none; the code

thanks for the help

Comment: Probably this question was already asked and answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204689/how-to-use-imacros-to-remove-a-part-of-element-inspector/38217344#38217344) .

Comment: if it was I did not think the answer is I am still in need of help

Comment: What is your 'iMacros' and browser versions?

Comment: I use Firefox 46 and imacro version 8.7 Because in INTAL Monthly Newsletter Current was removed several functions without Old HAS STILL All I need remover`style = "width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid # c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none; "using the URL GOTO = javascript:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try one of these lines:

```
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").style="display:<SP>block";undefined;}
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementsByName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].style="display:<SP>block";undefined;}
URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElementsByClassName("g-recaptcha-response")[0].style="display:<SP>block";undefined;}
```

I have no more variants.

Comment: thanks for the help the first code has done WHAT wanted